# Remove stateful EJB bean in client

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I'm currently learning EJB and as I understand when client gets a stateful session bean the server keeps it in memory(or passivates it) until the client removes the bean. Pretty simple, except nowhere I have seen any examples of how the client can actually remove the bean. How do you do that other than shutting down your client application? Or do I just have to implement a reset method in all my stateful beans if I want to start over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a business method that "ends" the flow, annotate it with @Remove.
Otherwise provide a "reset()" method with the @Remove annotation.

Comment: Thanks, I was going crazy with this :)